# Add space between Author, Date, and Abstract in YAML header

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

My YAML header looks like this, and I would like to change only the space between the author/date, and abstract.

How can I achieve this? I have tried using `\vspace{1cm}` after the date (failed), and also at the start of the abstract text, but that only spaces the text, and not "Abstract" itself.

Any ideas?

```
---
title: 
subtitle: 
author: "Me "
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`" 
abstract: "The document shows the answer to all questions & the output (as it relates to each)"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: false
    toc: false
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an up-to-date latex installation, you can use the hook system to add a bit of space before the `abstract` environment or the `\@date` macro which inserts the date:

```
---
title: "test"
subtitle: 
author: "Me "
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`" 
abstract: "The document shows the answer to all questions & the output (as it relates to each)"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: false
    toc: false
header-includes:
  - \AddToHook{env/abstract/before}{\vspace*{4cm}}
  - \makeatletter\AddToHook{cmd/@date/before}{\vspace*{4cm}}\makeatother
---

\maketitle


test
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It renders perfectly! Could you explain briefly what exactly is it that you specified? Reason being that I would like to know e.g. how I can also apply this to the space b/w author -- date

Comment: You have been extremely helpful! Much appreciated